# Get value from array of objects in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON which I keep in `strConfig` variable:

```
{
    "import": [
        {
            "drive": "F",
            "path": "F:\\\\PageExports\\\\",
            "pagestatus": "1",
            "withnextpages": "1"
        }
    ],
    "export": [
        {
            "drive": "F",
            "path": "F:\\\\PageExports\\\\",
            "followmainlink": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I transorm it to an object by:

```
var objConfig = jQuery.parseJSON( strConfig );
```

Could you tell me how do I get one of values from that object and assign it to a variable, please (let's say value of `import.pagestatus`)?
I tried:

```
console.log($(objConfig).find('export').find('pagestatus').value);
```

but that gives me 'undefined' in console. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `objConfig.import[0].pagestatus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code

```
 objConfig.import[0].pagestatus
```

it will give value of pagestatus inside import

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(resp);
var drive =  resp.import.drive;
alert(drive);
```

Comment: "_var drive =  resp.import.drive;_" really!!

Comment: var drive =  resp.import.pagestatus;

Comment: @HarpartapSinghPermar import is an array so either you target the values from indexes or use a loop to get it.